# Download all Twilio Call logs?

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to download all my twilio call logs (as it's explained here https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183588-Exporting-SMS-and-Call-Logs) but the problem is that this method is limited to 1000 logs. 
Any idea how can I download them all (csv)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation:](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/twilios-response)

> `PageSize` argument is limited to 1000 pages.
>
> When fetching multiple pages of API results, use the provided
>   nextpageuri parameter to retrieve the next page of results. All of the
>   Twilio Helper Libraries use the `nextpageuri` to page through resources.
>
> You should use the [Twilio Helper Libraries](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries) or `nextpageuri` and `previouspageuri` to navigate
>   through the resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Twilio Helper Libraries](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries) or [Twilio CLI](https://www.twilio.com/docs/twilio-cli/quickstart) to do so.

```
TWILIO CLI USAGE
  $ twilio api:core:calls:list

OPTIONS
  -l=(debug|info|warn|error|none)                                                 [default: info] Level of logging messages.
  -o=(columns|json|tsv)                                                           [default: columns] Format of command output.
  -p, --profile=profile                                                           Shorthand identifier for your profile.
  --account-sid=account-sid                                                       The SID of the [Account](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/api/account) that created the Call resource(s) to read.

  --end-time=end-time                                                             Only include calls that ended on this date. Specify a date as `YYYY-MM-DD` in GMT, for example: `2009-07-06`, to read only calls that ended on this date. You can also
                                                                                  specify an inequality, such as `EndTime<=YYYY-MM-DD`, to read calls that ended on or before midnight of this date, and `EndTime>=YYYY-MM-DD` to read calls that ended on
                                                                                  or after midnight of this date.

  --end-time-after=end-time-after                                                 Only include calls that ended on this date. Specify a date as `YYYY-MM-DD` in GMT, for example: `2009-07-06`, to read only calls that ended on this date. You can also
                                                                                  specify an inequality, such as `EndTime<=YYYY-MM-DD`, to read calls that ended on or before midnight of this date, and `EndTime>=YYYY-MM-DD` to read calls that ended on
                                                                                  or after midnight of this date.

  --end-time-before=end-time-before                                               Only include calls that ended on this date. Specify a date as `YYYY-MM-DD` in GMT, for example: `2009-07-06`, to read only calls that ended on this date. You can also
                                                                                  specify an inequality, such as `EndTime<=YYYY-MM-DD`, to read calls that ended on or before midnight of this date, and `EndTime>=YYYY-MM-DD` to read calls that ended on
                                                                                  or after midnight of this date.

  --from=from                                                                     Only include calls from this phone number, SIP address, Client identifier or SIM SID.

  --limit=limit                                                                   [default: 50] The maximum number of resources to return. Use '--no-limit' to disable.

  --page-size=page-size                                                           How many resources to return in each list page. The default is 50, and the maximum is 1000.

  --parent-call-sid=parent-call-sid                                               Only include calls spawned by calls with this SID.

  --properties=properties                                                         [default: sid,from,to,status,startTime] The properties you would like to display (JSON output always shows all properties).

  --start-time=start-time                                                         Only include calls that started on this date. Specify a date as `YYYY-MM-DD` in GMT, for example: `2009-07-06`, to read only calls that started on this date. You can
                                                                                  also specify an inequality, such as `StartTime<=YYYY-MM-DD`, to read calls that started on or before midnight of this date, and `StartTime>=YYYY-MM-DD` to read calls
                                                                                  that started on or after midnight of this date.

  --start-time-after=start-time-after                                             Only include calls that started on this date. Specify a date as `YYYY-MM-DD` in GMT, for example: `2009-07-06`, to read only calls that started on this date. You can
                                                                                  also specify an inequality, such as `StartTime<=YYYY-MM-DD`, to read calls that started on or before midnight of this date, and `StartTime>=YYYY-MM-DD` to read calls
                                                                                  that started on or after midnight of this date.

  --start-time-before=start-time-before                                           Only include calls that started on this date. Specify a date as `YYYY-MM-DD` in GMT, for example: `2009-07-06`, to read only calls that started on this date. You can
                                                                                  also specify an inequality, such as `StartTime<=YYYY-MM-DD`, to read calls that started on or before midnight of this date, and `StartTime>=YYYY-MM-DD` to read calls
                                                                                  that started on or after midnight of this date.

  --status=(queued|ringing|in-progress|completed|busy|failed|no-answer|canceled)  The status of the calls to include. Can be: `queued`, `ringing`, `in-progress`, `canceled`, `completed`, `failed`, `busy`, or `no-answer`.

  --to=to                                                                         Only show calls made to this phone number, SIP address, Client identifier or SIM SID.
```